# Jquery ajax - Check errors on server with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hope someone can give me an advice about how to do the following:

I have a form with some fields that I want to check (validate) on the server using Ajax - the Jquery way.

Of course what I would expect form the callback is to know if  each field has been correctly filled and thus validates.

I never done this before. Can anyone advice me what is the best way to do this?

Many thank for any help.
Francesco

Comment: Possible dupe.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505863/jquery-and-php-validation-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) has a error attr:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'youscript.php',
  success: function(data) {
    //whatever you want
  },
  error: function(data) {
    //this will be fired on error
  }
});
```

of course you can use any [form validation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/form-validation), but if the error occurs on server side, or if the user disable (somehow) your form validation plugin and the server side scripts fire up an error, the `error` attr should do what you want.

Comment: The `error:` callback is meant for HTTP errors (e.g. server not available or execution error). Usually you want to send a status value through the response `data` and evaluate it in the `success:` function as well.

Comment: Thank you bluefoot. I am using jquery to do some client validation but I need some validation to be done on the server too.

Comment: great. your sever should return the right HTTP status so that can work, like @mario said. Please, @Francesco, accept an answer or answer your own question with the results, if no answer was enough. Read the faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Bluefoot: what I am not sure about yet is how to get each error from the callback. I am calling the .php file (the one that makes the chekes on the server). If any error is found how do I collect them?

Comment: I am confident to how to collect 1/0 or false/true but not sure about an array of errors and how to show them on the page.

Comment: well you can return a [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) dict with the errors

Comment: Yes I thougth of using json. Acturally I am working on it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best jQuery ajax form submission plugin I've used.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Check out the examples page.